# ffmpeg segment_frames expected results

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to split apart a larger video according to a set of frame ranges I feed into ffmpeg.  Some questions in regards to the -f segment -segment_frames option and what is expecting/producing.  Here is what I am running:

```
ffmpeg -i full_movie.mov -f segment -segment_frames 123 -reset_timestamps 1 -c:a copy -map 0 "/Users/sjan/Desktop/%03d_test.mov"

ffmpeg -i full_movie.mov -f segment -segment_frames 124, 163 -reset_timestamps 1 -c:a copy -map 0 "/Users/sjan/Desktop/%03d_test.mov"
```

Will the first ffmpeg command go from 0 to 123 or 1 to 123?

Is the ffmpeg with the -segment_frames option starting at 0 when reading the QT Movie, considering this movie when opened in QT starts at 0?  Should I expect to feed it my frame ranges to account for this by subtracting 1 if it starts at 0?  I am seeing inconsistent results in proper ranges and it is likely due to this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, segment_frames starts from 0. As a rule of thumb, almost all index counters in ffmpeg start from 0.

So, `-segment_times 124,163` tells ffmpeg create a segment each for frames 0-123, 124-162, and 163-END. However, if these starting frames aren't keyframes, ffmpeg will start the segment with the first keyframe found after these frames.

Add `-break_non_keyframes 1` to force segmentation on the specified frames. However, initial frames may not decode correctly till a keyframe is found, if the segment is played standalone. Since you're encoding video, you can force keyframes at the segment points by adding `-force_key_frames expr:eq(n\,124)+eq(n\,163)`

Comment: How can I force it to use my frame range and not resort to keyframes?

Comment: See edited answer.

Comment: excuse my stupid question... but if I have a video where exactly are these key frames defined? Also I'm not seeing that -segment_times 124, 163 produces 124-162.  In fact, it is grabbing me 124-163, exactly 40 frames as opposed to what you say 39.

Comment: Share full log. Can't reproduce it here.

Comment: Log? I open up QuickTime, set frame display on and scroll to see frames.  It is always giving me the exact range 124-163 I specify in the command, not 1 less at end which is 124-162.

Comment: Run `ffmpeg -report -i seg-124 -vsync 0 -f null -` and share report file. Do it for the first segment as well.